# SAS: Cannot use where or if condition for specific variable.

Tags: sas

I have a dataset which has a variable. I could do proc freq to show following table:

[image: proc freq]

However I would like to output the observations were serumt=0.3:

```
data new;
set AIM12_OAW;
where serumt=0.3;
run;
```

I got error message as following:

NOTE: No observations were selected from data set WORK.AIM12_OAW.
NOTE: There were 0 observations read from the data set WORK.AIM12_OAW.WHERE serumt=0.3;

I tried

```
where serumt=0.21
```

still no observations. The weird thing was if I did

```
where serumt=0.12
```

it would output one observation (should be 6).

If I did

```
proc freq data=aim12_onw;
table serumt;
by serumt;
run;
```

The output would be:

[image: proc freq2]

I cannot understand why the variable serumt could not be selected by where or if statement.

I did check the format of serumt. It looks normal for me.

[image: format]

I have no idea how to deal with this variable. Thank you so much for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it might be a floating point precision issue - try something like

`where round(serumt,0.01) = 0.30`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It did work. How to avoid this in the future? Any suggestion to convert this variable to some other which can be recognized?

Comment: Round your variables at the point when you create them, or create rounded copies of them.